# cant tether samsung gs7 (android) to 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, android, tethering

brand new install of 16.04.1 desktop 32-bit. turning on tethering on the handset produces no additional connection in network manager. dmesg -w output includes the lines

```
rndis_host 1-2:1.0 eth0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:1d.7-1, RNDIS device, 00:00:00:00:00:00
rndis_host 1-2:1.0 enp0s29f7u1: renamed from eth0
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s29f7u1: link is not ready
```

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem on an OpenWRT router. The fact that the MAC address is listed as all zeros (`RNDIS device, 00:00:00:00:00:00`) seems to point to a problem, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: A similar issue (rndis_host [...] eth0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-[...] RNDIS device, 00:00:00:00:00:00) with a Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 and Ubuntu 16.04.2. Some bug?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. And as I see there are no answers although the question is 2 months old. So possibly you're still waiting for a solution.
I realized that the internet routes were not ok. The default route was missing.
You can check that with "route -n". If there is no route to 0.0.0.0, you got the error. You can add the default route with the command "sudo route add default gw XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX". You can get the required IP address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX by the command ifconfig. Look for inet address and change the number of the last group to 1. For example: 192.168.1.49 to 192.168.1.1. I tried to do this with the network manager, but I failed.
You also need to add a dns server. This should best be done with the network manager. So right click on the connection and add 8.8.8.8 as dns server or any other server you like.
I assume this is a bug in either the Samsung phone or Ubuntu. So this is more or less a workaround.

Comment: While it might be typical for the default gateway to have an address of xxx.xxx.xxx.1 it's by no means a certainty. To be certain use the command ` ip route | grep default`